# how log and rethrow the entire class

Tags: java, spring, exception

I'm using spring.

I have a class with multiple methods. In each method I have to write:

```
public void method1(){
    try{
       //anything
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       Log.error(e);
       throw e;
    }
}
public void method2(){
    try{
       //anything
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       Log.error(e);
       throw e;
    }
}
public void method3(){
    try{
       //anything
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       Log.error(e);
       throw e;
    }
}
public void method4(){
    try{
       //anything
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       Log.error(e);
       throw e;
    }
}
```

Can I write something to don't have to write this in each method? Maybe an annotation?

Comment: Check for `@ControllerAdvice` annotation in spring . link: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: What kind of exceptions do you expect? If I find someone catching plain Exception during code review, I usually reject it. If you are not handling anyway, why do you catch them?

Comment: I have to log here each exception. If we do abstraction on why I was doing that here, is there a solution to not repeat this try and catch in all methods?

Comment: Why not simply catching them on calling method then?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Spring, `@ControllerAdvice` would be a nice crispy solution for this case.

All you have to do is do some configuration and define your Global Exception handling class like so

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    // Handles Custom exceptions. MyException in this case
    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleMyException(MyException mex) {     
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        ...
        return model;
    }

    // Handles all the exceptions
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex) {     
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("errMsg", "This is a 'Exception.class' message.");
        ...
        return model;     
    }
}
```

Refer to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) post for configuring different types of error handling techniques in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to rethrow exception there are two solutions:

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
@SneakyThrows //annotation on method of lombok library

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils.rethrow;
rethrow() //method from Apache commons library
```

1)

```
@SneakyThrows(Exception.class) //without specifying will rethrow all exceptions
public void method1(){
       //anything
}
```

2)

```
public void method1(){
    try{
       //anything
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       Log.error(e);
       rethrow(e);
    }
}
```